# Uploading deobfuscation mapping.txt to Google Play by yml scripts on Azure

Tags: android, azure-devops, yaml, google-play, deobfuscation

I have established a pipeline on Azure to build and upload multiple build flavours onto Google Play with yml.  And I would like to push the corresponding mapping.txt.  However, I couldn't find any Azure resources on how to tackle this except feature requests which Ms have closed.

I have read [build, test, and deploy Android apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/android?view=azure-devops), but it only provides means to upload mapping.txt to app center.  I have also read [Visual Studio Team Services Extension for Google Play](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.google-play#google-play---release), but it is an UI driven approach which does not fit my purpose as I am uploading multiple APKs by yml.

May I ask for your advice on how to approach this please?